# Is there a \write18 bug in XeTeX or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: xetex, miktex, tikz-external, shell-escape

I'm using MiKTeX on Windows 10, latest stable packages on one computer, NEXT packages on the other computer. If I try to typeset the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\tikz\node{Hello};
\end{document}
```

at the point where the external compilation should start, XeTeX starts in interactive mode and with no input:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'xelatex -shell-escape -halt-on
-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "nodecolon-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalre
aljob{nodecolon}\input{nodecolon}"' ========
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6320 NEXT)
**
```

Is this a MiKTeX bug that I should report or did I miss something?

Comment: Doing well on Mac OS X

Comment: Works for me with TL'17 on Mac: I do notice that the TikZ team haven't picked up MD5 support in XeTeX, but that's different!

Comment: Works for me with TL2016 on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Works also with xelatex of TL2017 pretest on Linux.

Comment: There is a bug. The newest binary (which should repair this bug https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2597/) seems to have introduce a new problem. Report it. (I don't have the time now to reduce the example more).

Comment: I added a bug report. write18 seems really broken in xelatex. https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2598/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been solved in today's MiKTeX update (2017-04-24), repository version 6322.

Comment: is that the "next" version?

Comment: Even the non-NEXT.